# How to dynamically add to a MZ Select Option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase-realtime-database, materialize

I'm trying to dynamically add options to a materialize select. My cuurent code works in the form that if you inspect it and the elements will show all my options with the correct things but the drop down box doesnt show them.

```
salesBySold.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        var key = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();

        $('.salesperson-select').append(`
        <option value="${key}">${childData.name}</option>
      `);
    });
});
```

I've tried many things and read on here but none seem to fix it. The code above does what its supposed to do in appending the options but for some reason it wont display on the dropbox select

Comment: `childSnapshot.val()` or `childSnapshot.val` ???

Comment: log and share value of `snapshot`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Huh? The code works and shows me the name and keys but the dropdown select box doesnt display any options

Comment: can you share the output?

Comment: ```<select class="salesperson-select" tabindex="-1"><option value="" disabled="" selected="">Choose your option</option>              <option value="-Lclu9IQPmBbm5Sfe1IQ">Val</option>    
        <option value="-LcluFmAN4vkiJmHYF5N">Kenny</option>     <option value="-LcluIQZ-_9o3PxMboSs">House</option>
   <option value="-Lclu42FU2CyiZbcjeFN">Queen</option>    <option value="-LcluDd6McEp-SkqqA_X">Norris</option>  
   <option value="-LclU_psB6D_37ZB6RRu">Steve</option>
   <option value="-Lclu6_Vkk_WSrpvOFM3">Pierre</option> 
   <option value="-LclUXwKpZCK_wzgniO8">Ifeanyi</option></select>

Comment: Sorry, it was to long to be organized

Comment: I think you are using some plugin ..... then you have to re-initialize it